# Wordpress posts missing in the admin panel, but visible in the database

Tags: wordpress, bxslider

I use a downmloaded wordpress code, the home page displays two banner images banner.jpg and banner2.jpg.( it seems to used bxslider ). But I could se the code where the slider images embedded. It is in header.php. Code attached below.

I could see only 12 posts in the admin panel, but if I search the banner image names(banner.jpg and banner2.jpg.) in the database, I can see them in two separate  posts which are not available or access from the admin panel.
Database shows more than 200 posts, but admin panel shows only 12.

```
<!--banner starts-->

<?php if (is_front_page())

{

    ?>

<section class="banner">

  <ul class="bxslider">

  <?php
$type = 'slider';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
   ?>

    <li><img src="<?php echo $feat_image; ?>" alt=""/>

      <div class="banner-pattern"></div>

    </li>

    <?php endwhile; } ?>    



  </ul>

  <div class="banner-content-top">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-12">

          <div class="banner-content">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>

<?php } else

{

}

?>

<!--banner ends-->
```

My questions are:
1) which images are pulled by the code line
  (   **wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() )**)
displays. Is it the image we set as featured one in a post?

2) why the admin panel shows only 12 posts, even though the database has more than 200 posts in it?

3)  Why the posts with the banner image not visible in the admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm try to answer all your questions:

1) The function get_post_thumbnail_id() gets the featured image of your post.

2, 3) Maybe this website only have 12 posts. Wordpress save in wp_posts table, all the posts, pages and the navigation menu items.
You can read more about what stores in this table [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)